# AS920 Serial console pinout

Tags: cisco

some genius at Cisco decided that i would be a good idea to implement the serial console port (usually a RJ45 or DB9 connector) as USB-A connector. :-(

I have some of these boxes implemented in fiber POPs and like to implement Console-servers for Out-of-band management purposes in these fiber distribution sites.
As long as i don't find any specific "Cisco-ASR920 to worldwide common RJ45" cables i think that i have to build these by my own.

i tried the pinout as described in this Cisco community article (https://community.cisco.com/t5/networking-documents/asr-920-series-routers-console-port/ta-p/3754675), but this doesn't work for me.

has anybody successfully crafted such a cable and can provide me the layout how he connected the pins?

Comment: Why not just buy the correct A920-CONS-KIT-S= dongles?

Comment: Because i ordered two dozens of these boxes without any console cabling ... to be "green".
The Terminal servers are equipped with serial cables and we already have a few hundrets of the "blue ones" in our cellar... who could know that someone decided to do "something special" here. :-(

Comment: The blue cables connect to the dongles.. Just do it right. Building two dozen cables will be a giant pain, fraught with problem cables. It may be fine for one cable, but this is not something I would not risk my business on.

Comment: It's a bit too late, but you should've ordered the correct console cables with the devices. (there's never a reason not to as they're zero cost at that point.) Yes, using a USB connector looks like a very "chinesium" optimization.

Comment: @Ricky unfortunately no "zero colst" the A920-CONS-KIT-S= has a GPL price of 75€ - Funfact: the ASR920 has also an USB console port which is also a USB-A connector on the device side! So you need a USB-A-to-USB-A cable to connect to this Device ... crazy!

Comment: "-S" (without the equals) is what you get at the time of order. It's a "no additional cost" option when ordering the router itself. (or is when ordered from Cisco or a Cisco partner.) You've already ordered and received the hardware, so it's too late to add A920-CONS-KIT-S to those orders. (look up what one of those 3$ blue cables cost on the GPL. Some things you just don't want to buy from Cisco.)

Comment: @ricky you are right, ich checked CCW it is a 0€ Option ..

Comment: I'm too young to remember this, but wasn't there a day a couple decades ago when you could console to a router using the Aux port?  The pictures I see of the ASR920 show there's an RJ45 Aux port.  What does that get you?